# PHP images from function

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am a php newbie so please go easy.

I created queries for imgFld and imageFldName.
I am trying to find why my images from my db are not being displayed.

I have the below code:

```
image_show(stripslashes($row['imgFld']),stripslashes($row['imageFldName']));

echo ' '.$records_num;

function image_show($name_image, $alt_tag) {

    if (file_exists("mywebsite.co.uk/images/'$name_image'")) {
        $img = getimagesize('mywebsite.co.uk/images/'.$name_image);
        echo '<img src="mywebsite.co.uk/images/'.$name_image.'" alt = '.$alt_tag.' border=0 align="bottom"';
        echo 'width = '. $img[0] .' height = ' .$img[1] . ' />';
    } else {
        echo 'Add an image here';
    }

}
```

Im getting the image names from a column inside my db and each column has an 'image.jpg', connecting it with the img src script from HTML so that I can display the images from the db.

However no images are being displayed and I cant find the error. Doesnt seem like anything is wrong. 
When I echo $name_image nothing is produced.

Comment: shouldn't you add http:// before the image location? :)

Comment: the image location is a local static folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case it means that there is nothing populating the `$name_image` variable.

Assuming that website directory is a local one, the cause of this is most likely your arguments when you call the `image_show` function. They do not match the order you have specified.

The first argument should be the name and the second the alt text, as defined:

```
function image_show($name_image, $alt_tag)
```

However you are passing the id to `$name_image` and the name as `$alt_tag`.

That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [file_exists](http://php.net/file-exists) is only for local files.

For example:

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/files/image.jpg')) {
...
}
```

Comment: the directory of the images is local..I had given it a fake name to post on here. The directory is not mywebsite.co.uk

Comment: another typo ? hehe... try to use this, including documen_root. Greatings!